# When does Irish Stamp Duty apply for UK investors buying Ireland domiciled shares?

Tags: taxes, stocks, united-kingdom, ireland

Let us assume I am a UK resident with a UK-based trading account, considering to buy Ireland domiciled ETF shares, such as VWRL.

I am confused whether I will have to pay Irish Stamp Duty of 1% or not.

The stockbrokers list 1% Irish Stamp Duty in their costs section:

- Barclays - [When is Stamp Duty and PTM Levy charged?](http://help.stockbrokers.barclays.co.uk/help/buying-selling/stamp-ptm-levy-charge/)
- Hargreaves Lansdown - [Share dealing charges](http://www.hl.co.uk/shares/share-dealing/dealing-charges)

However, other sources on the Internet indicate otherwise:

- http://monevator.com/vanguard-etfs-uk/ - "They’re Irish domiciled, so you skip stamp duty."
- http://www.fool.co.uk/news/investing/2012/05/16/buying-the-ftse-just-got-cheaper.aspx - "HL should not be charging stamp duty on any Irish-domiciled ETF. That doesn't mean they won't try, only that you should complain if they do." and "i bouhgt the ishares via HL, and no stamp duty was paid" [sic]

Who is right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And I messaged my broker who responded:

> Thank you for your enquiry. Irish domiciled ETFs on the LSE are stamp exempt so you do not have to pay the 1% duty.

(previously I had called the and the lady on the phone said I have to pay it)

Also, I found this page which lists ETFs as exceptions for which stamp duty is not payable:

http://www.londonstockexchange.com/traders-and-brokers/security-types/etfs/education/what-are-etfs/what-are-etfs.htm

So basically while I think I would have to pay stamp duty if I would want to buy, say, Aer Lingus Group shares, ETFs are an exception and exempt.