# Stamp tax duty on UK stocks: when does it apply?

Tags: stocks, united-kingdom, commission, stamp-duty

Some sources on the Internet tell that [buying shares on UK stocks](https://www.gov.uk/tax-buy-shares) is assessed to a stamp tax duty of 0.5% of trade value for UK stocks and 1.0% of trade value for Irish listed stocks.

I recently bought shares in a Ireland-domiciled ETF using an EU-based broker. Following the transaction I don't see any commission to cover the stamp duty.

Please explain in which cases the stamp tax duty is not charged on UK stocks. May it vary from broker to broker?

#### Similar questions

- an unanswered one [Stamp duty on UK share purchases made by non-UK residents](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/144745/stamp-duty-on-uk-share-purchases-made-by-non-uk-residents)
- one for UK residents [When does Irish Stamp Duty apply for UK investors buying Ireland domiciled shares?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21248/when-does-irish-stamp-duty-apply-for-uk-investors-buying-ireland-domiciled-share) (relies on broken links).

Comment: ETFs aren't stocks or shares

Comment: Isn't ETF just a fund that offers shares in its stock in a stock exchange? How does it differ from shares of a regular company?

Comment: @Peggy.  It's different because it's not a company.  So far as HMRC is concerned it's more like an OEIC (open-ended investment company) fund, which just happens to trade on the stock market.  See https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/stamp-taxes-shares-manual/stsm101060

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing/blending "ETFs" and "stocks".  But they aren't the same (if "stocks" is taken to mean company shares) and different rules can apply to them.

Fortunately ETFs are fairly exempt from stamp duty these days.  At https://www.justetf.com/uk/news/etf/how-to-buy-an-etf-frequently-asked-questions.html it says

> Do I pay a transaction tax when I buy an ETF?
>
> No. On most UK share purchases, there is a transaction fee called
> Stamp Duty charged at 0.5%. However, stamp duty is not payable on
> overseas domiciled ETFs that trade in London. ETFs from the main
> providers are all domiciled in Ireland, Luxembourg and France. Stamp
> duty on UK-domiciled ETFs was abolished in April 2014.

and at https://www.investcentre.co.uk/articles/index-investing-doesnt-have-be-taxing there is

> ETF trades themselves are exempt from Stamp Duty in most
> jurisdictions, including the UK. This means that the secondary trade
> in the ETF is essentially exempt from Stamp Duty.

amongst other relevant but quite technical information.